# How to get info on what key was pressed on for how long?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keypress

Imagine this code:

```
if (navigator.appName == "Opera")
    document.onkeypress = function (e) { console.log(e.keyCode); };
else 
    document.onkeydown = function (e) { console.log(e.keyCode); };
```

What it does is pretty obvious, I guess. The problem is, if you hold the key for a long period of time, it will be registered a lot of times. In my app, this is a problem because it makes my app do a lot of unnecessary computing. Is it possible to somehow only get a `keypress` once, but with info on how long the key was held?

Comment: I'm no expert on logic or anything but shouldn't the branches of an if statement differ? `:)`

Comment: Do you use a library like jQuery?

Comment: Oops, yes, you're right, of course they should differ %)
No, I don't use jQuery or any other framework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var pressed = {};

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if ( pressed[e.which] ) return;
    pressed[e.which] = e.timeStamp;
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if ( !pressed[e.which] ) return;
    var duration = ( e.timeStamp - pressed[e.which] ) / 1000;
    // Key "e.which" was pressed for "duration" seconds
    pressed[e.which] = 0;
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EeXVX/1/show/

(remove the "show/" part of the URL to view the code for the demo)

So you have the `pressed` object which monitors which keys are currently being pressed and at what point (in time) they have been pressed.

Inside the keyup handler, you determine if the key was being pressed, and if so, calculate the duration by subtracting the time-stamps of the keyup/keydown events.

Comment: @popoffka Be aware that this code doesn't work in Opera and older versions of IE (IE8 and below)...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing somethign like,

1. onkeydown, remove keydown listener.
2. onkeyup, attach keydown listener again and computer the time?

Comment: Of course you would have to also take other possibilities in to consideration. Like what if the onkeyup never got triggered.

Comment: That wouldn't work for parallel key-presses (multiple keys pressed at the same time).