# Get a List of currently pressed keys, whitout keyup/keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, onkeydown, onkeyup

I had a curious problem today: A script, that always worked before, stopped to work because apparently 'keyup' was fired directly after every 'keydown' event, killing some events that waited for long keypresses.

After testing around, I found out that my synergy was responsible for that.

Finally, I found a solution to the problem: A jQuery extension that allowed me to delay (and collect) certain events, namely http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

```
$(window).keyup( $.debounce(100, onKeyUp) )
```

This worked for a bit, until I noticed another problem: Multiple keys at once. Let's say, you press the 'up' button, and the 'left' button - and then let go of both at the same time. the $.debounce() will handle both as the same keyup event, letting the event only fire once and causing `event.keyCode` to only contain one key instead of both.

The simplest solution would be, to check all the keys pressed when the keyup event is fired, not relying on `event.keyCode` since it's incomplete in this case.

My problem is: how can I find out what other keys are still pressed, **whitout relying on keydown / keyup events?** (since they wont work, because of synergy)

```
function onKeyUp(event) {
    // get all keys pressed
}
```

Is there some kind of `window` variable keeping track of the keys?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please explain _what_ you're trying to do (from the start)?

Comment: I want to get a list of all keys currently pressed (and held down) by the user, whitout relying on keyup / keydown events.

Comment: And what do you mean by `my synergy was responsible for that`?

Comment: synergy allows one to share the same keyboard / mouse between two computers. Apparently, this seems to cause some problems with keydown / keyup events (after _every_ keydown event, a keyup event is fired, even if you didnt let go of the key yet) - this causes some issues if you're trying to do something _while_ the user is pressing a key

Comment: Your question looks very similar to one of my own questions (which already has an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640061/get-a-list-of-all-currently-pressed-keys-in-javascript

Comment: Anderson Green - that question has an answer which uses keyup/keydown, so definitely not relevant.