# How can a web pages prevent paste events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paste

In researching my Super User question [How can I selectively disable paste blockers](https://superuser.com/q/858082/16858) I discovered that the specific site I had a problem with did not appear to use any of the methods any of the existing solutions expected.

While the global solutions of using the `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` preference or [Disable clipboard manipulations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nocopypaste/) plugin in FireFox worked, they also also suffer the problem that there *are* legitimate reasons why websites might want to hook into `onpaste` (such as google docs rich text support or facebooks link handling) so I don't want that functionality completely disabled.

The solutions we have found (such as Derek Prior's [Re-enabling Password Pasting on Annoying Web Forms](http://prioritized.net/blog/re-enabling-password-pasting-on-annoying-web-forms/) and the improved [Re-enabling Password Pasting on Annoying Web Forms (v2)](http://chrisbailey.blogs.ilrt.org/2013/01/03/re-enabling-password-pasting-on-annoying-web-forms-v2/) by Chris Bailey) which use bookmarklets to selectively disable the functionality of [paste blocking code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1226574/42473) don't appear to work with [this page](https://www.petplanet.co.uk/purchase/logon.asp).

This makes me wonder, how does the *petplanet* website disable paste, why don't the existing solutions work with this site, and what other ways are there to prevent paste blocking? Answering these questions should help us write a comprehensive bookmarklet solution, so this pernicious practice can be worked around for good.

Answer (score 2):

You can jQuery `paste` event to listen for the event and use `prevenrDefault()` to prevent the event.

In [this](https://www.petplanet.co.uk/purchase/logon.asp) page , they used the below jQuery

```
$('#pwd, #pwd2').bind('paste',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Please type your password.')
});
```

Open Firebug, Go to Scripts Tab, then search the string  `Please type your password.` (Firebug Search Bar , not browser search bar.) , you'll find above code. And Code is present logon.asp

[image]
To **Disable** it , you simply use `off` method like this `$('#id1').off()`. this unbinds all events for the element that has `id='id1'`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only 'disable' such things with JavaScript.

As I can imagine not really the answer you are looking for, you could do something like this:

```
var keys = [];
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        checkCombinations(e);
    },
false);

window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    },
false);

function checkCombinations(e){
    // try and prevent cntrl+v (paste)
    if(keys["v".charCodeAt(0)] && e.ctrlKey){
        alert("You're not allowed to paste");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Source: [Get a list of all currently pressed keys in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640061/get-a-list-of-all-currently-pressed-keys-in-javascript)