# How browser highlight text without adding any tags around word

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me that how the browser highlight text (when we use ctrl+f and search any word) without dom manipulation or with adding any tag around the word.
I have to implement search functionality on my application, where i have online book creator and its preview. User can find any word with search button and i am showing list of that found word. Where user click on any item in list i have to send user to particular portion of word.
After that i am showing that word with highlighted background (which is hide after 1 second).
But when i add span tag with highlight class and remove it, the lines in books are moving in some cases if the word found at the end of line.

```
<span class="highlight">The word founded by search</span>
```

Then i see the browser's search functionality, i can see browser din't add any tag to highlight text. May be because of its doing by canvas. Can anybody help me about the problem, can i highlight text without adding any  tag or class or how the browser exactly do this.

Comment: Use the .keypress( handler ) https://api.jquery.com/keypress/ and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeypress

Comment: @JoseMarques what's the role of keypress event here for highlighting?

Comment: This is perhaps a way to use contr + f. Now how do you want to select the word to look for?

Comment: i gave a search box where user type the word and press enter.  Then i am showing the list of sentence within word found. Where user click the particular item, i am taking user to particular position and highlight that sentence for a second.

Comment: to do contr + f give a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once#.

Comment: Now that you have a trigger a text input and you have text to search for. You have to find a way to compare the text individually. I think the best way is to take the text and separate it and then compare it with the text input

Comment: for reference you can go to https://www.safaribooksonline.com/home/ and open one book. and on right side panel here is a search option. Find the word and see list. that exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: This might help - http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-underline-particular-word-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Create the text for test purposes:

```js
function myFunction() { //This function is for test purposes
document.open();
var data = document.write("hih This part is for test purposes   uihuiuuh hhhiuh hhihi Hello World gukhjggkhgkghkghkgkkg hvbhjj bjhbjhhjhbgjhb jkjkjhjkh hkjhkjh jhjkhkj jhjkhkj jhkj kjhjkhk hjkhkjhjkh jjjjkjhiooigsesres lllljlk kjlj  hgfgfhgfghfgfhgfgfhgfytfytftfytfytffftfftyftftyfdrdres hihhhggyg gvghggfhgf jjgygjyg hjgjhgjhg hhjgg hbhjb");
document.close();
$("#dvContent").html(data);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to open an output stream, add some text, and close the output stream.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id = "dvContent">
</div>
```

If you want to open an external document

Jscript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lesen").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "helloworld.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success : function (data) {
                    $("#dvContent").html(data);
                }
            });
        });

});
```

html:

```
<div id = "dvContent" >
</div>
```

Creat your key press trigger exemple from [Get a list of all currently pressed keys in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640061/get-a-list-of-all-currently-pressed-keys-in-javascript/13651016#13651016)

```js
var keys = [];
document.body.innerHTML = "Keys currently pressed: "
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = e.keyCode;
        var keysArray = getNumberArray(keys);
        document.body.innerHTML = "Keys currently pressed:" + keysArray;
        if(keysArray.toString() == "17,65"){
            document.body.innerHTML += " Select all!"
        }
    },
false);

window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        document.body.innerHTML = "Keys currently pressed: " + getNumberArray(keys);
    },
false);

function getNumberArray(arr){
    var newArr = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(typeof arr[i] == "number"){
            newArr[newArr.length] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Manipulate the trigger to make a textbox appear to enter the text or word that we are looking for.

```js
var keys = [];
 
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = e.keyCode;
        var keysArray =keysArray = getNumberArray(keys);
        document.body.innerHTML = "Keys currently pressed:" + keysArray;
        if(keysArray.toString() == "17,65"){
           var str_comp = prompt("Text to find", "");
           keys = [];
           document.body.innerHTML = "";
           document.body.innerHTML = str_comp;
        }
    },
false);

window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        document.body.innerHTML = getNumberArray(keys);
    },
false);

function getNumberArray(arr){
    var newArr = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(typeof arr[i] == "number"){
            newArr[newArr.length] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

A Simple find text script http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-underline-particular-word-using.html Provided by  **@T.Shah**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dvWords = $("#dvContent").html().split(' ');    
  var dvHTML = ''
  for (i = 0; i < dvWords.length; i++) 
  {   
     if (dvWords[i].toLowerCase() == 'jquery') 
     {
        dvHTML += ' ' + '<span>' + dvWords[i] + '</span>';
     }
     else
     {
         dvHTML += ' ' + dvWords[i];           
     }
   }    
   $("#dvContent").html(dvHTML);
});
```

```css
body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
}
#dvContent span
{
   text-decoration: underline;
   font-weight : bold;
   color : Blue;    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvContent">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. jQuery In nulla est, congue quis sagittis vel, ullamcorper euismod mi. Duis gravida, nibh id placerat sagittis, quam tellus vestibulum nisl, a feugiat augue ipsum sit amet urna. Sed semper urna non odio bibendum blandit. Etiam eu jQuery orci ut arcu commodo dignissim. Curabitur sit amet massa velit. Fusce in felis ac ipsum ultrices elementum. Suspendisse potenti.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur jQuery adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse turpis nulla, mattis et scelerisque vitae, eleifend dictum nibh. Suspendisse at felis velit, sed sollicitudin enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. jQuery Quisque sed purus ac enim volutpat iaculis eget et risus. Donec consequat odio vel sem dignissim eu venenatis nisl vehicula. Suspendisse potenti.

Maecenas et arcu et quam dapibus lobortis. Curabitur tincidunt tincidunt dictum. jQuery Sed porta cursus jQuery sodales. Cras sodales, ipsum non molestie malesuada, erat lacus faucibus orci, id venenatis leo nibh quis purus. Proin eu sem vitae felis pellentesque suscipit vitae id erat. In eros mi, egestas non cursus ac, bibendum ac nisl. Cras convallis elit jQuery in felis congue ut consectetur ipsum egestas.

Pellentesque jQuery felis elit, posuere ut aliquet id, fermentum et purus. Quisque ac nunc vitae sapien eleifend sollicitudin. Proin nisl est, congue et adipiscing nec, rutrum non eros. Sed ultrices ullamcorper justo, in lobortis quam mollis ac. Proin ac lacinia eros. Integer jQuery suscipit consectetur scelerisque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean sem sapien, sollicitudin sed sodales non, cursus nec ipsum. Aenean pretium eros non felis accumsan vitae tristique quam dapibus. Donec eget quam sed sem varius rutrum eget nec mi. jQuery Cras ut ipsum nisl.
</div>
```

To conclude, let's put it all together

```js
var keys = [];
var data = myFunction();
$("#dvContent").html(data); 
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = e.keyCode;
        var keysArray =keysArray = getNumberArray(keys);
        if(keysArray.toString() == "65,68"){
           var str_comp = prompt("Text to find", "");
           get_str_eql(str_comp, data);
           keys = []; 
        }
    },
false);

window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        getNumberArray(keys);
    },
false);

function getNumberArray(arr){
    var newArr = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(typeof arr[i] == "number"){
            newArr[newArr.length] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}

function myFunction() { //This function is for test purposes
var data = "hih This part is for test purposes uihuiuuh hhhiuh hhihi Hello World gukhjggkhgkghkghkgkkg hvbhjj bjhbjhhjhbgjhb ola jkjkjhjkh hkjhkjh jhjkhkj jhjkhkj jhkj kjhjkhk hjkhkjhjkh jjjjkjhiooigsesres ola lllljlk kjlj  hgfgfhgfghfgfhgfgfhgfytfytftfytfytffftfftyftftyfdrdres hihhhggyg gvghggfhgf jjgygjyg hjgjhgjhg hhjgg hbhjb ola";
return data;
}

function get_str_eql(string_val, data_val){ 

   
  var dvWords = data_val.split(" ");
  
  var dvHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < dvWords.length; i++) 
  {  
     
     if (dvWords[i] == string_val) 
     {
        dvHTML += " " + "<span>" + dvWords[i] + "</span>";
     }
     else
     {
         dvHTML += " " + dvWords[i];           
     }
   }    
   $("#dvContent").html(dvHTML);
}
```

```css
body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
}
#dvContent span
{
   text-decoration: underline;
   font-weight : bold;
   color : Red;    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id = "dvContent">
</div> <br> 
</br>
<p>Click in the keys 'a' and 'd' to make the search.</p>
```

It's working. Now it's just a little more work, and you have a word search system.

Comment: I'll improve this example.

Comment: Still does not work. In the morning I solve the last details

Comment: If you have doubts or want to improve, just ask.

Comment: yes i figure out your code, but as i wrote in question, i am looking for solution that how browser highlight text without using tag. Can we do that in our site? I dont want to add any span  or other tag with class to add.